# How to take backup of a BigQuery view script using BQ?

Tags: google-bigquery

Apart from clicking on copy table in BQ console, is there anyway to copy a BQ table from one schema to another using a BQ script?

Comment: do you need to materialise data from the view and make a backup of that to a table or would you like to create another view (code) with the previous view code?

Comment: I have to do both. I want to know if there is a way to use bq script to generate a copy of table as well as copy of the view that is written already. @fpopic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you would like to backup view's sql query code only:

```
bq mk \
--nouse_legacy 
--view "$(bq show --view --format=prettyjson project1:dataset1.view1 | jq --raw-output .view.query)" \
project2:dataset2.view2
```

I used [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) json tool.

In case you would like to materialise the view into table:

```
bq query --nouse_legacy --destination_table=project1:dataset1.table1 "SELECT * FROM project1.dataset1.view1"
```

Update:

In case you would like to copy exisiting table to another just do

```
bq cp project1:dataset1.table1 project2:dataset2.table2
```